# find corresponding row value for start and end of column sequence

Tags: r, match, sequence

I have a column which describes whether an activity is present or not (0,1) which is in a chronologically ordered data frame. I'd like to get the time that the activity (each series of 1's) starts and ends each time throughout the data set and the corresponding positional data.

i.e with the following data set;

```
library(chron) 

tt <- times(1:200/144) 

time <- chron(rep("1/1/09", length = length(tt)), tt) 

activity <- rep(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0),times=10)

lat <- runif(200,-10.8544921875,2.021484375)
lon <- runif(200,56.82380908513249,62.478568831926395) 

df <- data.frame(time,activity,lat,lon)

# i'd like to end up with this
start <- c("01/01/09 01:20:00","01/01/09 04:40:00","01/01/09 
08:00:00","01/01/09 11:20:00",
       "01/01/09 14:40:00")

end <- c("01/01/09 03:10:00","01/01/09 06:30:00","01/01/09 
09:50:00","01/01/09 13:10:00",
    "01/01/09 16:30:00")

startLat <- c(rep("appropriate_value",5))

startLon <- c(rep("appropriate_value",5))

endLat <- c(rep("appropriate_value",5))

endLon <- c(rep("appropriate_value",5))


result <- data.frame(start,end,startLat,startLon,endLat,endLon)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dplyr's `lag` and `lead` functions, it's easy to check when the value of `activity` changes:

```
library(dplyr)

df$next_activity <- lead(df$activity)
df$prev_activity <- lag(df$activity)

start <- df$time[df$activity == 1 & df$prev_activity == 0]
end   <- df$time[df$activity == 1 & df$next_activity == 0]
```

To obtain a data frame with start and end times/coördinates:

```
df_start <- filter(df, activity == 1 & lag(activity) == 0) %>%
  select(start_time = time,
         start_lat = lat,
         start_lon = lon)
df_end <- filter(df, activity == 1 & lead(activity) == 0) %>%
  select(end_time = time,
         end_lat = lat,
         end_lon = lon)

result <- cbind(df_start, df_end)
```